# Slow start of mappers after reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am using ChainReducer to build the following pattern

```
Map1 --> Reduce --> Map2
```

I want Map2 step to start only after the completion of Reduce step. Is there a property in hadoop map reduce to set this.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is the following:

```
ChainMapper.addMapper(generalConf, Map1.class, ..., new JobConf(false));
ChainReducer.setReducer(generalConf, Reduce.class, ..., new JobConf(false));
ChainReducer.addMapper(generalConf, Map2.class, ..., true, new JobConf(false));
// execute the job with generalConf
```

The above code will guarantee that the execution of the `Map2`, will only start when `Reduce` has finished.

Comment: I used the same code. the second mapper does not wait for the reducer to complete. the second mapper will start processing as the reducer writes the data and does not wait for the completion

Comment: @user1690436 Are you sure you are passing the same configuration to ChainMapper and ChainReducer? Could you please post this part of your code?